# C# Syntax - Remove last occurrence of ';' in string from split

Tags: c#, .net, string, arraylist, split

I have a list of strings stored in an ArrayList. I want to split them by every occurrence of ';'. The problem is, whenever I try to display them using MessageBox, there's an excess space or unnecessary value that gets displayed.

Sample input (variable = a):

```
Arial;16 pt;None;None;None;None;None;None;FF0000;None;100;Normal;None;Normal;
```

Below is a line of code I used to split them:

```
string[] display_document = (a[0] + "").Split(';');
```

Code to display:

```
foreach (object doc_properties in display_document)
{
   TextBox aa = new TextBox();
   aa.Font = new Font(aa.Font.FontFamily, 9);
   aa.Text = doc_properties.ToString();
   aa.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
   aa.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 25);
   aa.ReadOnly = true;

   doc_panel.Controls.Add(aa);
   doc_panel.Show();
   pointY += 30;

}
```

The output that displays are the following:
[image]

How do I remove the last occurrence of that semicolon? I really need help fixing this. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: Use `a.Trim(';').Split(';')`, or `a.TrimEnd(';').Split(';')`.

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  Assuming `a[0]` is your semicolon separated string, your last entry would be an empty string, not a semicolon.

Comment: I think the other commentors are missing an important fact.  `s.Split(';')` will return an array whose elements will never contain a semi-colon.  Or at least it's not supposed to.  I can't reproduce this, but if that's really what's happening, something mysterious is going on.

Comment: @recursive: That is actually quite clear to me, but what can we do? :) Let's close the question as off-topic since no repro code is provided.

Comment: No repro on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zFh808)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt It be easiest to check if the input ends with a ";" before splitting it, and if so remove the last character? Sample code:

```
string a = "Arial;16 pt;None;None;None;None;None;None;FF0000;None;100;Normal;None;Normal;";
        if (a.EndsWith(";"))
        {
            a = a.Remove(a.LastIndexOf(";"));
        }
        //Proceed with split
```

Comment: I'd argue the easiest option would be to use the overload of `Split` that allows your to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, but OP has given us conflicting information in his question.

Comment: Actually, the ; cannot appear in OP code so this answer helpfulness is equal to that of my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Split will not print last semicolon if no space character is added and your input is a string.

I don't know why you prefer an array list (which probably is the reason of this strange behaviour) but if you could use your input as a string you could try that

```
string a = "Arial;16pt;None;None;None;None;None;None;FF0000;None;100;Normal;None;Normal;";
string[] display_document = a.Split(';');
foreach (object doc_properties in display_document)
{
    //The rest of your code
}
```